# Spring Boot custom query returns relation "todo" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm currently writing my first Spring Boot application where I wan't to create a basic todo app.

The database works fine as long as I only use the CRUD functions and as soons as I call my own query I get this error:

```
2018-11-19 10:00:36.353 ERROR 25065 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "todo" does not exist
```

My ToDoController:

```
package ch.aintevenmad.todo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

@RestController
public class ToDoController {
    private ToDoRepository repository;

    public ToDoController(ToDoRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/todo")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public Collection<ToDo> allToDo() {
        return new ArrayList<>(repository.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/first")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ToDo firstToDo() {
        return repository.findAll().get(0);
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public void deleteToDo(ToDo toDo) {
        repository.delete(toDo);
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ToDo addToDO() {
        Date date = new Date();
        ToDo toDo = new ToDo("Hello", date, false);
        repository.save(toDo);
        return toDo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/countcompletedtasks")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public int countCompletedTasks() {
        return repository.countCompletedTasks().size();
    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteall")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public void deleteAll() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/loaddefaults")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhots:4200")
    public void createDefaults() {
        repository.save(new ToDo("PMB", false));
        repository.save(new ToDo("GMDU", false));
        repository.save(new ToDo("INMA", true));
        repository.save(new ToDo("SLGP", false));
    }

}
```

My ToDo Class:

```
package ch.aintevenmad.todo;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ToDo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private @NonNull
    String taskName;
    private Date dueDate;
    private String extraNote;
    private boolean taskCompleted;

    public ToDo(String taskName, boolean taskCompleted) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.taskCompleted = taskCompleted;
    }
    public ToDo(String taskName, Date dueDate, boolean taskCompleted) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.taskCompleted = taskCompleted;
    }
}
```

My ToDoRepository:

```
package ch.aintevenmad.todo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import java.util.Collection;

@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public interface ToDoRepository extends JpaRepository<ToDo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ToDo WHERE taskCompleted = true", nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<ToDo> countCompletedTasks();
}
```

Did I set up my project wrong or did I misunderstand how custom queries work with Spring Boot?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Thanks Tu.ma you found the problem. Postgresql didnt call the table todo as expected but to_do so of course it didn't fine the table...

Comment: Can you check how the table is called in postgresql? Without going through Spring.

Comment: Thanks Tu.ma you found the problem. Postgresql didnt call the table todo as expected but to_do so of course it didn't fine the table...

Comment: If you found a solution, then post that solution as an answer, do not edit your question for that. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question (and accept your own answer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Tu.ma you found the problem. Postgresql didnt call the table todo as expected but to_do so of course it didn't fine the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your query like below.

Your true statement should be like 'true' instead of true only.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public interface ToDoRepository extends JpaRepository<ToDo, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ToDo WHERE taskCompleted = 'true'", nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<ToDo> countCompletedTasks();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the **default constructor** for Todo entity.

Comment: @NoArgsConstructor does it for him.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could just use one of spring's built in queries:

```
Collection<ToDo> findByTaskCompletedIsTrue();
```

If you really need the number only (as your method's name suggests), you can also use countBy

```
Long countByTaskCompletedIsTrue();
```

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-boot) for more queries